# chntpw hex on windows 10 registry entry crashes to get bt session key

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, bluetooth, windows-10

I am trying to pair my bt keyboard for both windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04. The Problem is I am not able to get the key with chntpw because after I want to hexdump the keyboard registry-entry, the program crashes because of a Segmentation fault. This is my second try to read out the session key.

(At first I was trying to read the key out in win 10 with regedit, but I can't get the permission to read this key out. Changing the owner on Windows is not possible (no permission) even though I run regedit as admin.)

Here you can see what I was doing to get the key with chntpw:

```
chntpw -e SYSTEM
chntpw version 1.00 140201, (c) Petter N Hagen
Hive <SYSTEM> name (from header): <SYSTEM>
ROOT KEY at offset: 0x001020 * Subkey indexing type is: 686c <lh>
File size 18874368 [1200000] bytes, containing 4008 pages (+ 1 headerpage)
Used for data: 285621/17878016 blocks/bytes, unused: 198/335616 blocks/bytes.

Simple registry editor. ? for help.

> ls
Node has 15 subkeys and 0 values
  key name
  <ActivationBroker>
  <ControlSet001>
  <DriverDatabase>
  <HardwareConfig>
  <Input>
  <Keyboard Layout>
  <Maps>
  <MountedDevices>
  <ResourceManager>
  <ResourcePolicyStore>
  <RNG>
  <Select>
  <Setup>
  <Software>
  <WPA>

> cd ControlSet001/Services/BTHPORT/Parameters/Keys

(...)\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Keys> ls
Node has 1 subkeys and 0 values
  key name
  <xxxxxxxxxxxxxx>

(...)\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Keys> cd xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

(...)\BTHPORT\Parameters\Keys\xxxxxxxxxxxxxx> ls
Node has 1 subkeys and 0 values
  key name
  <yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy>

(...)\BTHPORT\Parameters\Keys\xxxxxxxxxxxxxx> hex yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Now after hours of trying I don't know what to do to get this key. Has anybody an idea what I could try out?

Greets

Comment: The problem was that I went to ControlSet001 instead of CurrentControlSet. Now I have access to all the data I need.

Comment: You're skipping the important part of your answer... You don't have a CurrentControlSet path in your output.

Answer (score 2):

OP might already have his answer but for people (like me) who stumbled over the same error because they didn't pay attention.
yyyyyyyyyyy is not a value but a subkey.
So, you have to cd into yyyyyyyyyyy where you'll find a couple of values.
In my case this was a folder because it was a Bluetooth LE device. Not sure if this is only the case for Low Energy devices, though.